# I want to develop optimizer on llvm by myself, how can I build for it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, llvm

I want to research and develop the optimizer-level in llvm by myself.

How can I build the llvm source code from GitHub?

My question is, I have followed the step in the document of llvm-project in GitHub. But the size of builds is too huge, and my computer cannot handle it.

I searched the issue on internet, and I found some command for it.

```sh
cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=HOST -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
```

Is this right?

But the variable `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` may build without debug build. I don't know if this is fit for me because without debug build, maybe I will be difficult to develop optimizer, right?

So, my purpose to build llvm-prject is - **mini-size of frontend and mini-size of backend.**

Comment: Is it the file size or RAM usage that is too high?

Comment: Yes, the files occupied almost 30GB and my disk was full. So the make process was terminated by itself.

Comment: Well, the disk space is more or less cheap these days, so you'd better just get new HDD/SDD.

Comment: Below is my cmake command which occupies around 3GB. cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang"  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC $HOME/llvm-project/llvm